# Compiler skipping nested ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, foreach, swiftui

This is a simplified version of my problem, although it's passes compiling, the compiler doesn't get inside the ForEach statement at all at run time. I set a breakpoint and it's just skipping it.

On the real app I am using two different Views under the if statement and pass some objects to them, but to simplify it the problem exists on simple Text views as well.

```
    import SwiftUI

struct assignmentsView: View {
    
    var tChar : String
      
    var hourAssignments : AssignmentsByHour

    
    var body: some View {
         
   
                    HStack {
                        Text(self.tChar).padding()
                        
                        ForEach(self.hourAssignments.assignments){
                             assignment in
                            ForEach(assignment.assignments){
                                internalBody in
                                HStack {
                                  
                                   
                                    if(self.hourAssignments.isEmptySlot){
                                        Text("SomeText")
                                    }else{
                                     Text("SomeText")
                                    }
                                    }
                                   
                            }
                    
                }
          }
    }
}
```

Other classes code:

AssignmentsByHour

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct AssignmentsByHour:Identifiable{
    

    var id:UUID
    var num : Int
    var assignments : [AssignmentsPerHour]
    var isEmptySlot:Bool
    
    init(isEmptySlot:Bool,num:Int,assignments:[AssignmentsPerHour])
    {
        id=UUID()
        self.num=num
        self.assignments=assignments
        self.isEmptySlot=isEmptySlot

    }
 

}
```

AssignmentsPerHour

```
import Foundation


struct AssignmentsPerHour:Identifiable{
    
    var id:UUID
    var assignments : [AssignmentPerHour]


    init(assignments:[AssignmentPerHour])
    {
        id=UUID()

        self.assignments=assignments

    }
 
}
```

AssignmentPerHour

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct AssignmentPerHour:Identifiable{
    
    var id:UUID
    var assignmentName : String
    var height:CGFloat

    
    init(height:CGFloat,assignmentName:String)
    {
        id=UUID()
        self.assignmentName=assignmentName
        self.height=height

    }
 
}
```

I am not sure if it's related, but when trying to use `id:\.self` in the ForEach I am getting :

```
Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'AssignmentsPerHour' conform to 'Hashable'
```

Although as far as I understand, to use ForEach it's only needed to be confirmed to identifiable which the class the error talks about, is.

Comment: You need to post a minimal reproducible example for us to help. We don't know what `AssignmentsByHour` is, and what it's set to.

Comment: Added, I needed  three classes in order to produce an array inside an array of custom object. Didn't like it at all, but the alternative for my needs was worst.

Comment: Ok.. and are you sure that you're creating the structure that has elements in `AssignmentsPerHour.assignments`?